# Are App.config files language-agnostic?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clr, app-config

Can we use the same App.config file regardless of the .Net language that we used to make our program? Are there any language-specific elements (e.g. for C#, ILAsm etc.) that could prevent CLR to work properly if used with project of similar structure but written in another .Net language?

Answer (score 3):

.Net languages all compile to MSIL code.

The runtime, which loads the config file, does not know or care how the MSIL was generated.

However, some languages may have their own runtime libraries (eg, `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`), which may read their own config sections.